# View not refreshing after pop-up triggers Action

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I’m currently building a mobile application for iPad using MVC4 and Jquery Mobile.  I have a pop-up box that is opened by a jquery function (a function that is triggered by a user click of an item on a page that is sitting inside of an iFrame in the View).  Once the pop-up appears, the user is able to click “Yes” or “No” (as a confirmation) .  If the user clicks “Yes”, I am triggering an Action in my controller in order to do some database work.  Once the work of the Action is completed, I return to the same View where I started, only with new information in my model that I now want displayed.
Most of this works.

The pop up is triggered correctly, the action is appropriately triggered when “Yes” is clicked, and I can step through the action and see my database work completing correctly and reloading my model with the new information.  I can even step through and see that it’s calling the correct view upon return View, and that the new model information is reaching the HTML helpers.

However, the page in Safari never refreshes.  It’s still the same as before I went to my Action.  I’ve even tried returning another view entirely to see if that would cause it to refresh, but the old page stays there stubbornly.

Here's the relevant code from my view (WOTest):

```
@section Header 
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#popupSubmit').bind('click', function () {
                 $.post('@Url.Action("LoadTestData", "WO")', 
                 {CompKey:lblCompKey.innerHTML, ServiceRequestNumber:lblServiceRequestNum.innerHTML}); 
               });                              
        });



        function newWorkOrder(compkey, comptype, unitid) {
                        $('#popupDialog').popup('open');
                        $('#lblCompKey').html(compkey);
                        $('#lblCompType').html("CompType: " + comptype);
                        $('#lblUnitID').html("Unit ID: " + unitid);
       }


    </script>     
}

@section Content 
{ 
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSRTemp", "WO", FormMethod.Post))
        {           

            <div class="ui-grid-c" style="margin-bottom:6px;">  
                <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:32%; padding-right:2%;">  
                    <label id="lblAddress" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Asset Address:<br /></label> 
                    @Html.TextBox("AssetAddress", Model.AssetAddress, new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
                    { "readonly", "true" }, { "data-mini", "true" } })  
                </div> 
                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:22%; padding-right:2%;"> 
                    <label id="lblAsset" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Asset:<br /></label>
                    @Html.TextBox("Asset", Model.Asset, new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
                    { "readonly", "true" }, { "data-mini", "true" } }) 
                </div> 
                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:15%; padding-right:2%;">  
                    <label id="lblAssetID" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Asset ID:<br /></label>
                    @Html.TextBox("AssetID", Model.AssetID, new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
                    { "readonly", "true" }, { "data-mini", "true" } })   
                </div> 
                <div class="ui-block-d" style="width:31%;">  
                    <label id="lblLogComment" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Log Comment:<br /></label>
                    @Html.TextArea("LogComment", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-mini", "true" } })   
                </div> 
            </div>  
            <div class="ui-grid-c"> 
                <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:25%; margin-top:8px;">
                    <label id="lblAssignedTo" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Assigned To:<br /></label>
                     @Html.DropDownList("assignedTo", Model.listOfActiveEmps, "Select Employee", new { data_mini = "true" }) 
                </div> 
                <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:20%; margin-left:5px; margin-top:8px;">
                   <label id="lblPriority" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">Priority:<br /></label> 
                   @Html.DropDownList("priority", Model.listOfPriorities, "Select Priority", new { data_mini = "true" }) 
                </div> 
                <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:25%; margin-top:8px; margin-left:5px;">
                   <label id="lblWOType" style="font-weight:bold; color:#28608E;">WO Type:<br /></label> 
                   @Html.DropDownList("woType", Model.listOfWOTypes, "Select WO Type", new { data_mini = "true" }) 
                </div> 
                <div id="divCreateButton" class="ui-block-d" style="float:right; margin-top:27px;">                  
                    <input id="btnCreateWO" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" type="submit" style="height:35px;" value="Create WO" />               
                </div> 
            </div>
        }      

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false"
            style="max-width:416px;" class="ui-corner-all">

                <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                    <h1>Asset Selection <label id="lblServiceRequestNum" style="text-align:left;  height:22px; font-size:14px;">@Model.ServiceRequestNumber</label> </h1>
                </div> 
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">      
                    <h3 class="ui-title" style="text-align:center; height:22px;">Are you sure?</h3>                             
                    <label id="lblCompKeyLabel" style="text-align:left;  height:22px; font-size:14px; margin-left:95px;">Comp Key: </label>                  
                    <label id="lblCompKey" style="text-align:left;  height:22px; font-size:14px;"></label>  
                    <label id="lblCompType" style="text-align:left;  height:22px; font-size:14px; margin-left:95px;"></label>                   
                    <a id="popupSubmit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back"
                    data-mini="true" data-theme="b" style="width:150px;" type="submit">Yes</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" 
                        data-mini="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" style="width:150px;">No</a> 
                </div> 

        </div>         

    </div>  
    <h5>@ViewBag.Message</h5>             

    <div class="ui-grid-solo"> 
        <div id="mapDiv" class="ui-block-a" style="margin-top:8px; width:100%;">  
            @{  
                string xPoint = "?xPoint=" + @Model.XCoordinate;
                string yPoint = "&yPoint=" + @Model.YCoordinate;
                string _uri = "/test/Map.htm" + xPoint + yPoint;
                if (Request.IsLocal)
                    _uri = "../../Map.htm" + xPoint + yPoint; 
                <iframe id="mapIframe" width="100%" src="@_uri"></iframe>
             }  
        </div> 
    </div>
```

The pop-up calls this Action, in WOController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadTestData(string CompKey, string ServiceRequestNumber)
    {
       //Do Database stuff, load model properties with new info
       return View("WOTest", srModel); 

     }
```

This Action should return the same view (WOTest) with new info in the model.  I've step through the Action code, it works as expected.  The srModel sent to WOTest at the end has the correct new information...anyone have any ideas why it isn't displayed in WOTest?  It's as if WOTest doesn't refresh at all.

I've tried using ModelState.Clear, but that didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this, I ended up solving my own issue by separating the part of my view that I needed to update into a partial view.  I then put a placeholder div (#detailsDiv) in my main view (WOTest).  I also changed my Action (LoadTestData) to returning the partial view instead of returning the main view.  So, I altered my jquery so that the partial view is loaded with the model data on click of the pop-up's submit button like so:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#popupSubmit").bind("tap", tHandler);

        function tHandler(event) {
            $.post('@Url.Action("LoadTestData", "WO")', { CompKey: lblCompKey.innerHTML, ServiceRequestNumber: lblServiceRequestNum.innerHTML }, 
            function (data) { $('#detailsDiv').html(data); $('#detailsDiv').trigger("create"); });
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, this only solves my issue in desktop Safari...I'll have to find another solution for iPad.